How do I map by postal code with geojson in superset/deck.gl?
I'm looking at switching from Metabase to Superset, though one visualization in particular is giving me trouble in replicating.
Namely, I want state-level postal code maps to show customers.  Results are like "Customer A,Zipcode,Products Sold" where I'd want to see at a glance where clusters of customers are.
In metabase I upload a geojson file that maps zip-codes to polygons and then associate the zipcode column, though I'm not sure exactly how I can do this with superset - there's a deck.gl geojson plugin, is that what I could use?  Will I need to transform the geojson file somehow?  I see a "GEOJSON COLUMN" but does that mean I'd need that json in the dataset itself?
